# how to send data and URL using jquery load method

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I want to send the value of variable x to the contoller using jquery `load()` method
Currently i am working like this as shown in below code and its working fine but i want to sent the value of `x` to the controller i am using `spring mvc`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function loadXMLDoc()
{
   $( "#bdeRightView" ).load( "${contextPath}/clusterInfoView");
 } 
 </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bdeViewNew').on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [],x;

        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim());
              x = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim();
            if(x=="abc" || x=="xyz" || x=="pqr")    
                {
                return true ;
                }
            else{
                $('#treeBreadCrumbs').html(r.join(', '));
                loadXMLDoc();
            } 
        }
    });

   });
 </script>
```

Now my controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clusterInfoView", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getClusterInfoView() {
    try{

        System.out.println("inside try of controller ");
       // some code goes here 

        return new ModelAndView("");

    }
     catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return new ModelAndView("errorMessage");
        }


 }
```

My question is how i can get the value of `x` in this controller method so that i can use this `x` as per my requirement.

can any one knows how to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: x value is one or more than one..if one you take the hidden input type in jsp page i.e id.add to hidden id..you take that value in controller as @RequestParam("input type name") String x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$( "#bdeRightView" ).load("${contextPath}/clusterInfoView?x=" + escape(x));`

The `escape()` function **encodes a string.** so you will get the value as `x= ram sharma` in your `controller`

Comment: yes that work now i am getting proper value of x. if possible can you see below statement is fine or not?: String sql = "select * from abc where Host_Name='hostDetails.getHostName().trim()'";   i want query something like this: String sql = "select * from abc where Host_Name='ram'";

Comment: That's Great my friend

Comment: Dear pravin love to do that i can't see any option to upvotes

Comment: Dear Pravin can you please see my one more question if possible  the topic of question is GET request from a jsp to controller and send a string value with action.   thanks a lot

Comment: hi pravin if possible can look to one more query with topic : how to give action in java script for get method using jsp values

Comment: Can you share link of it here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124859/how-to-give-action-in-java-script-for-get-method-using-jsp-values

Comment: Hi pravin if i want to send one more value to controller with x what should be the syntax i mean with x i want to send y also using jquery load function.

Comment: `$( "#bdeRightView" ).load("${contextPath}/clusterInfoView?x=" + escape(x)+"y=sanjay");`                                                                   you will get `sanjay` as y in your `controller`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pravin i tried like this $("#bdeRightView").load(   "${contextPath}/clusterInfoViewNew?x="+""+escape(x) +"" + "&y="+"" +escape(y)+"");

Comment: hi @Pravin if possible can you look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670644/how-to-pass-the-list-of-radio-buttons-name-to-spring-controller-and-show-them-to

Answer (score 1):

You can pass x as GET parameter like this:

```
"${contextPath}/clusterInfoView?x=" + x
```

then in controller:

```
public ModelAndView getClusterInfoView(@RequestParam("x") String x)
```

Comment: thanks a lot kamil. one more doubt for eg if x=ram then its coming to controller but if x= ram sharma then in controller only ram is coming so how i can get complete value of x if it has spaces also