# how to give action in java script for get method using jsp values

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

Hi i am giving a get request from a jsp page as shown below:

```
     <c:forEach items="${empNameInfo.empName}"  var="empNameDetail">

         <a href="${contextPath}/empValues?empName=${empNameDetail.eName}&   amp;empNo=${empNameDetail.eNo}">Emp Details </a></c:forEach>
```

And its working fine. But now i want to use it in java script so that i can refresh a particluar of other page (i.e. A.jsp having above code but from here i want to refresh the of B.jsp) so how i can give same kind of request in java script so that i can use load method and change a particular content. i mean how i can get `${empNameDetail.eName}`  `${empNameDetail.eNo}` in javascript.

or is their any other way to do the same pls let me know

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script>
    function myFunction(name,no){
      alert(name+"  "+no);
     }
  </script>

     <c:forEach items="${empNameInfo.empName}"  var="empNameDetail">

     <a href="${contextPath}/empValues?mpName=${empNameDetail.eName}&empNo=${empNameDetail.eNo}" 
      onclick="myFunction('${empNameDetail.eName}','${empNameDetail.eNo}')">

         Emp Details </a>
    </c:forEach>
```

Or

You can directly use `JSTL` in your `java-script` code

```
   <script>
      <c:forEach items="${empNameInfo.empName}"  var="empNameDetail">
         var name = "<c:out value='${empNameDetail.eName}'/>" ;
         alert(name);

       </c:forEach>
  </script>
```

Comment: pravin i got both the values in my java script code as u shown above so i want to pass two parameter to call action  $( "#bdeRightView" ).load("${contextPath}/empValues?mpName?empNo="+escape(eName)+","+escape(eNo)); is it correct but it seems some syntax error is still their??

Comment: `<a href="${contextPath}/empValues?mpName="+escape('${empNameDetail.eName}')+"&empNo="+escape('${empNameDetail.eNo}') >`

Comment: hi pravin please have a look for this question if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169820/how-to-get-complete-parent-node-name-in-js-tree-while-selecting-the-child-node?noredirect=1#comment42830656_27169820   thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi Pravin if you get time pls help me for above given link of question regarding jstree.

Comment: I got no idea about `jstree`