# How to get the ancestors of a JS tree node when it is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am getting the child tree name but I want to get its complete hierarchy of parent node names.

Below code shows how I get the child node and print its value in a particular div element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bdeViewNew').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var i, j, r = [];

        for (i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
            r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text.trim());
            $('#treeBreadCrumbs').html(r.join(', '));
        }
    });
});
```

Now it prints the value of child node, e.g. `Child a`. But I want something like follows, if the tree structure is as shown below:

```
Parent
  Child 1
    Child a
    Child b
  Child 2
    Child c
    Child d
```

so if I click on `Child a` I want my div content updated as

```
Parent > Child 1 > Child a
```

as of now I am getting `Child a` only. Please let me know how I can get the correct output.

I tried like this as shown below to get path of all the parent node:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#bdeViewNew').on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
var ids = data.inst.get_path('#bdeViewNew' + data.rslt.obj.attr('id'),true);
var names = data.inst.get_path('#bdeViewNew' + data.rslt.obj.attr('id'),false);
alert("Path [ID or Name] from root node to selected node = ID's = "+ids+" :: Name's = "+names);
 });
 });
```

but still no result to get_path. Do I need to use different JS or a plugin? And what is the meaning of attr('id') i should pass the id of that li or something else as i did'nt understand this syntax properly.

Adding my jstree:

```
 <div id="bdeViewNew">
    <ul>


        <li id="bde" data-jstree='{"opened":true,"icon":"./images/tree.png"}'">
            Parent 1

            <ul>

                <li id="aaa" data-jstree='{"opened":true,"icon":"./images/tree.png"}'>
                    Child 1 <c:forEach items="${empInfo.empList}"
                        var="empValue">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="bbb" data-jstree='{"icon":"./images/tree.png"}' >${empValue.empName}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </c:forEach>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li id="ccc" data-jstree='{"icon":"./images/tree.png"}'>Child 2
                    <c:forEach items="${imgInfo.imgList}"
                        var="imgValue">
                        <ul>
                            <li id="ddd" data-jstree='{"icon":"./images/tree.png"}'>${imgValue.imgName}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </c:forEach>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: check for its parents

Comment: @Manticore  i tried using one function to check for parent node but its not working as below: y=r.push(data.instance._get_parent(data.selected[i]).text);
    alert(y);  if you have any other info regarding function pls let me know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will work fine... it will get the full parents...

```
    $('#bdeViewNew').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var loMainSelected = data;
        uiGetParents(loMainSelected);
    });

    function uiGetParents(loSelectedNode) {
        try {
            var lnLevel = loSelectedNode.node.parents.length;
            var lsSelectedID = loSelectedNode.node.id;
            var loParent = $("#" + lsSelectedID);
            var lsParents =  loSelectedNode.node.text + ' >';
            for (var ln = 0; ln <= lnLevel -1 ; ln++) {
                var loParent = loParent.parent().parent();
                if (loParent.children()[1] != undefined) {
                    lsParents += loParent.children()[1].text + " > ";
                }
            }
            if (lsParents.length > 0) {
                lsParents = lsParents.substring(0, lsParents.length - 1);
            }
            alert(lsParents);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert('Error in uiGetParents');
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this correct  for (var ln = lnLevel -1; ln >= 0 ; ln--) {
                  var loParent = loParent.parent().parent();
                  if (loParent.children()[1] != undefined) {
                      lsParents += loParent.children()[1].text + " > ";
                  }
              }   ??

Comment: check the latest answer sanjay.. Just i stored the result in array and reverse the array. Now u will get the result

Comment: I m also using it but i get undefined on  loParent.children()[1].text . Do you have any ideas? i m using jsTree 3.1.1

Comment: @RavikumarRaman Hi...This code works perfectly for me.  I am trying to post the alert message to a php file...which is not working at all.  I have made a post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363615/jstree-checkbox-variable-not-getting-posted-to-a-php-file would you be able to have a look please.

Answer (score 5):

```
var node=$('#drives_tree').jstree("get_selected", true);
$("#breadcrumbs").text($('#drives_tree').jstree().get_path(node[0], ' > '));
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer by far. Using the build-in get_path is the cleanest way to get a breadcrumb without depending on DOM parent.parent.parent calls.

Comment: obviously it is the easiest way i found to get complete path of selected node

Answer (score 2):

**We have direct method to get the parent information.**

```
  $('#bdeViewNew').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var loMainSelected = data;
        alert(loMainSelected.node.parents);
    });
```

**It will return ["Child1", "Parent"] . Using this method we can get the all the parents up to root.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravi for your reply  i am getting the ids if i want the node name then what needs to use and is their any way i can get output like Parent > child as i have shown at the top

Comment: Ravi please let me know if is thier any way to get output like [Parent > Child 1 > child a ] if i just select on child a. as what you u suggested i m getting the ids of that node but i want to show actual node name. please let me if you have any idea to do this  thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Sanjay we have alternate method .

Comment: Hi Sanjay,
 Step 1 : Get the Selected node Id and selected node level
 Step 2 : Using node id get the current parent like this ( ex.. $("#101000000892").parent().parent() )
  step 2.2 : Next level node ( $("#101000000892").parent().parent().parent().parent() )
  step 2.3 : stroe this in a vairable  var loNode = $("#101000000892").parent().parent();
  step 2.4 : Next you can  loNode.parent().parent()
 Step 3 : Using for loop u can loop through the level until reached 1.
 step 4 : Now you can get the full text .

Answer (score 2):

```
function uiGetParents(loSelectedNode) {
    try {
        var loData = [];
        var lnLevel = loSelectedNode.node.parents.length;
        var lsSelectedID = loSelectedNode.node.id;
        var loParent = $("#" + lsSelectedID);
        var lsParents = loSelectedNode.node.text + ' >';
        for (var ln = 0; ln <= lnLevel - 1 ; ln++) {
            var loParent = loParent.parent().parent();
            if (loParent.children()[1] != undefined) {
                lsParents += loParent.children()[1].text + " > ";
                loData.push(loParent.children()[1].text);
            }
        }
        if (lsParents.length > 0) {
            lsParents = lsParents.substring(0, lsParents.length - 1);
        }
        alert(lsParents);
        alert(loData.reverse());
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert('Error in uiGetParents');
    }
}
```

**The result stored in array loData . and just reverse the data and loop the loData Array. You got u r output**

Comment: hi @ Ravi kumar Raman if possible can you look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670644/how-to-pass-the-list-of-radio-buttons-name-to-spring-controller-and-show-them-to

Answer (score 0):

**

```
Step 1 : Get the Selected node Id and selected node level
        Step 2 : Using node id get the current parent like this ( ex.. $("#101000000892").parent().parent() )
            step 2.2 : Next level node ( $("#101000000892").parent().parent().parent().parent() )
            step 2.3 : stroe this in a vairable  var loNode = $("#101000000892").parent().parent();
            step 2.4 : Next you can  loNode.parent().parent()
        Step 3 : Using for loop u can loop through the level until reached 1.
        step 4 : Now you can get the full text .
```

**

Comment: Hi ravi thanks for answer but i have have tried like this to get the id of selected node but its giving me ids of its parent too. $('#bdeViewNew li').click(function() {
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
        alert($(this).text());
       });  if possible based on obove code can you write some steps so i get it porperly. and how i will get step 1 mention by you ? pls write the code for step 1 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Instead of angular.each, use a for loop.

You will get an arry with all the text of the nodes.

```
var breadcrumbArr = [selectedNode.node.text];

angular.forEach(selectedNode.node.parents, function(element, index) {
    if (element === '#') return;
    breadcrumbArr.push($('#'+element).find('a:first').text())
});

breadcrumbArr.reverse();

return breadcrumbArr;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less verbose version that prints Parent > Child

```
function uiGetParents(node) {
try {
    var level = node.node.parents.length;
    var elem = $('#' + node.node.id);
    var text = node.node.text;

    for (var ln = 0; ln <= level - 1 ; ln++) {
        elem = elem.parent().parent();

        var child = elem.children()[1];
        if (child != undefined) {
            text = child.text + ' > ' + text;
        }
    }

    console.log(text);
}
catch (err) {
    console.log('Error in uiGetParents');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = $tree.jstree().get_node(id),
    formatted_name = $tree.jstree().get_text(node);

    $.each(node.parents, function(key, parentId) {
        if ( parentId !== "#" ) {
            var parent = $tree.jstree().get_node(parentId);
            formatted_name = $tree.jstree().get_text(parent) + "->" + formatted_name;
        }
    });

   console.log(formatted_name);
```