# how to pass the list of radio buttons name to spring controller and show them to the success page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have a list of radio buttons while selecting
I am facing one issue with below code as i am getting only value of first radio button in my js function for others (i mean other than first radio) it is giving null. PFB code

```
 <tr> <td> <input type="radio" id="selectedTempList" name="template" value="${templateList.finalTemplateName}" onclick="getSelectedTempName()"></td> <td><c:out value="${templateList.finalTemplateName}"></c:out></td></tr>
```

My java script function

```
 $("#selectedTempList").each(function() {
     if($(this).is(':checked'))
         selectedTemplateName=$(this).val();
     });
     alert("radio select values"+selectedTemplateName);

 }
```

Comment: What error you getting.? And can u please share controller code. ?

Comment: pravin i am getting these values in controller but as now i am selecting 2 buttons r1, r2 so i get those in my function and i will pass them two controller. But user can select any no. of radio buttons so all checked button needs to get in a list inside javascript and then i can pass list of selected radio button to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var radioValueArrya = [];
$("#r1").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        radio1=$(this).val();
        radioValueArrya.push(radio1); 
        alert("radio select values"+radio1);
    });



 $("#r2").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            radio2=$(this).val();
            radioValueArrya.push(radio2);
        alert("radio select values"+radio2);
    });   
// controller call 
 $("#divid").load("${contextPath}/actionName?kRadio="+escape(radio1)  +"" +
                    "&sRadio="
                    +"" +escape(radio2)+"&radioValueArrya="+radioValueArrya);
```

And in your JSP file use `<input type="hidden" id="radioValueArrya" name="radioValueArrya"/>`

And in your Controller add parameter `@RequestParam List<String> radioValueArrya` in your method

Comment: Pravin thanks. i have one more query, this selected radio button's name i am saving in a table and at a condition i am showing list of name fetching from table. Now these list of  names also i want to show as radio button and user can select only once at a time. But here in my code we select all names
 <c:forEach items="${Details.listOfRadios}"  var="radioList">
 <table> <tr> 
  <td>  
<input type="radio" id="${radioList.finalValue}" name="${radioList.finalValue}"       value="${radioList.finalValue}"></td>
 <td><c:out value="${radioList.finalValue}"></c:out>
 </td></tr> </table>
 </c:forEach>

Comment: no problem while display buttons but at a time i want to select only one radio not multiple from a list of radio buttons

Comment: you need to have same name for group of radio button in which you want to achieve above

Comment: pravin do have any idea about parallel execution pls refer ths que if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805723/how-to-run-sh-script-on-multiple-different-node-of-a-hadoop-cluster-using-java